Mutation for MixedVariable problem in pymoo
I have a multi objective optimization problem that should be solved to minimize two objective functions of 6 variables. the first variable is Integer and the others are Real. I use MixedVariableGA() to solve the problem. However, the mutation is not work with this class. Hear is a part of the code I developed:
class Multi_Objective_Problem(ElementwiseProblem):
    
    
    def __init__(self, cost_fun_evaluator, **kwargs):
        
        self.cost_fun_evaluator = cost_fun_evaluator
        x1_L = 10       # Integer variable
        x1_U = 500      # Integer variable
        x2_L = 1.0
        x2_U = 8.0 
        x3_L = 2.0
        x3_U = 9.0                 
        x4_L = 2.0
        x4_U = 9.0
        x5_L = 2.0
        x5_U = 30.0
        x6_L = 2.0
        x6_U = 30.0
        vars = {'x1': Integer(bounds=(x1_L, x1_U)),
                'x2': Real(bounds=(x2_L, x2_U)),
                'x3': Real(bounds=(x3_L, x3_U)),
                'x4': Real(bounds=(x4_L, x4_U)),
                'x5': Real(bounds=(x5_L, x5_U)),
                'x6': Real(bounds=(x6_L, x6_U))}
        
        super().__init__(n_obj=2, n_ieq_constr=0, vars=vars)
                         
                         
        
        
    def _evaluate(self, X, out, *args, **kwargs):
        x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6 = X["x1"], X["x2"], X["x3"], X["x4"], X["x5"], X["x6"]
        solution = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6]
        y1, y2 = self.cost_fun_evaluator.objective_function(solution)
        out["F"] = [y1, y2]
        
        
        
 
problem = Multi_Objective_Problem(cost_fun_evaluator=cost_fun)
mutation = PolynomialMutation(prob=0.25, eta=8)


algorithm = MixedVariableGA(pop_size=110,
                            survival= RankAndCrowding(),
                            mutation=mutation,
                            )

# Run GA:
result = minimize(problem, 
                  algorithm, ('n_gen', 100),
                  seed=1,
                  verbose=True)

I use seed = 1 to evaluate the effect of mutation on the results but the results are constant for every value for prob and eta in PolynomialMutation().
I also define a custom mutation class to perform mutation based on the type of variables as follows:
    class CustomMutation(Mutation):
        def _do(self, problem, X, **kwargs):
            for i in range(len(X)):
                if np.random.random() < 0.9:  # Mutation probability
                    if isinstance(problem.vars["Len"], Integer):
                        X[i]["x1"] = np.random.randint(problem.vars["x1"].bounds[0], problem.vars["x1"].bounds[1] + 1)             
                    if isinstance(problem.vars["x2"], Real):
                    X[i]["x2"] = np.random.uniform(problem.vars["x2"].bounds[0], problem.vars["x2"].bounds[1])
                    if isinstance(problem.vars["x3"], Real):
                    X[i]["x3"] = np.random.uniform(problem.vars["x3"].bounds[0], problem.vars["x3"].bounds[1])
                    if isinstance(problem.vars["x4"], Real):
                    X[i]["x4"] = np.random.uniform(problem.vars["x4"].bounds[0], problem.vars["x4"].bounds[1])
                    if isinstance(problem.vars["x5"], Real):
                    X[i]["x5"] = np.random.uniform(problem.vars["x5"].bounds[0], problem.vars["x5"].bounds[1])
                    if isinstance(problem.vars["x6"], Real):
                    X[i]["x6"] = np.random.uniform(problem.vars["x6"].bounds[0],   problem.vars["x6"].bounds[1])
        return X


and used this class in defining the algorithm:
      algorithm = MixedVariableGA(pop_size=110,
                            survival= RankAndCrowding(),
                            mutation=CustomMutation(),
                            )

However, the results are constant. Pleas help me how I can define Mutation operator for this problem in MixedVariableGA().
Thanx
I expect to have different results when I change the mutation probability. However, the results are constant regardless of the mutation probability value.
